# Display pictures from a folder in the cente of full screen

Tags: vb6, vb5

I have two groups of pictures saved in two folders. I want the program to display theses pictures randomly in center of full screen form. I am trying to do this with visual basic.

```
Private Sub VScroll1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Form2.Show
    Form1.Hide
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()

   If Interval > 0 Then
       Timer1.Enabled = True
   Else
       Timer1.Enabled = False
       Form2.Hide
       End
   End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Image control to display the picture and if your Image control name is "Image1", Then you can use the following **to reposition your image in center** every time you change the picture.

```
Image1.Left = (Me.ScaleWidth - Image1.Width) / 2
Image1.Top = (Me.ScaleHeight - Image1.Height) / 2
```

The following are added:

You have to place a FileListBox control in your form and name it `f`

```
Dim folder As String
Dim n As Integer

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    n = Rnd() * f.ListCount

    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(folder & "\" & f.List(n))

    Image1.Left = (Me.ScaleWidth - Image1.Width) / 2
    Image1.Top = (Me.ScaleHeight - Image1.Height) / 2

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    folder = "D:\VLTR"

    f.Visible = False
    f.Pattern = "*.jpg"
    f.Path = folder
End Sub
```

Comment: for now i want to know how to load and display pictures randomly from folder?

Comment: please what vb version you are using ? i trued it with vb 6 but showing error with "pattern" that method or data member not found

Comment: Visual Basic 6.0 Enterprise Edition